# Blacklisting Drivers

Tags: linux, drivers

What does it mean to blacklist a driver in Linux/Unix? How do you go about doing it?

Answer (score 3):

In openSUSE 11.4 you can find it in the file /etc/modprobe.d/50-blacklist.conf. At the top you find a description:

> Listing a module here prevents modprobe from loading it via modalias
>   (only aliases from /lib/modules/*/modules.alias). You may still load
>   it explicitely. We blacklist some modules because they may harm on
>   certain devices or they prevent other modules from grabbing the
>   device.

On other distributions it should be done similarly. I am not sure if other Unixes support this in the same way.